# After upgraded from VS2008, build project in VS2012 shows error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, upgrade

Our team is migrating whole baseline from VS2008 to VS2012. There're over 400 C++ projects.  There're 6 C++ project show wired error, such as :

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: SSLT, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1> stdafx.cpp
1> ???
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '???': No such file or directory
1> ??????????????????????????????
1>c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '??????????????????????????????': No such file or directory
All files which are the parameters of cl.exe seems in wrong encoding, and cl.exe can't find them.
Firstly, i think it must be encode issues of .vcxproj, so i save as other encoding style. But still happens.
Then i re-upgrade these projects with such issue, but always build error.
```

At last, I change the project platform toolset back to VS2008, then build pass. So i think it's not because project file encode format. I don't know what wrong with them when using 2012 compiler. These projects build no error using 2008 compiler. And as i know from VS2010, project format changed a lot, so i can't find any clue.

Comment: Do you really see the filenames as `???` or did you just hide them from us?

Comment: The compiler will also have a problem displaying the name of the file.  Seeing ??? is somewhat expected when the filename contains Unicode characters that cannot be displayed in console's default encoding.

Comment: Thanks your reply, I find root cause today. The root cause of mess file name issue is now clear now. it is because that wrong precompiling head file reference.

Answer (score 1):

Btw, there's another reason cause such issue. After upgrade, there's one property in *.vcxproj file made an unproper line break, such as:
     /Zm300 
      /bigobj %(AdditionalOptions) 
if i change it back to:
    /Zm300 /bigobj %(AdditionalOptions)
Then works well, build pass.

The projects which has such issue, 80% of them are because of such issue.

Comment: Those two strings are identical.  this makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a new sample project to see which encoding the VS expects and then convert your files to it.
- Alternatively, [How to: Upgrade Visual C++ Projects to Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh690665.aspx) says that you must upgrade a VS2008 project upon opening it in VS2012.

I don't have a VS2012 installation to check this, but there may be a function to convert a project programmatically in one of its DLLs - try searching with a `dumpbin`-based script or by examining stack traces with `procmon` while converting a sample project.

Comment: Thanks your reply, I find root cause today. The root cause of mess file name issue is now clear now. it is because that wrong precompiling head file reference.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, i automatically upgrade our projects using: devenv.exe /upgrade *.vcproj in script.
Today i find the root cause is precompile header file: stdafx.h.
It is because that wrong precompiling head file reference. It will cause mess file name issue.